# Windows 7 Drive Letter Changed on Data Drive and Can't Log In

Tags: windows-7, ssd, users

I just purchased an SSD for my computer to install the Windows OS files and my program files on, and for my other hard drive for my user directory. I got it all working through an answer file in audit mode on the install, but since Windows ran a check disk, it changed my data drive letter and I can no longer log in. It says something along the lines of "the user profile service failed the logon" and my profile picture does not appear on the log in screen.

Eventually I found out how to boot into safe mode and use command prompt and diskpart to force the drive letter to what it was when I installed to it, but it still is failing to log in, however the profile picture does show up now, which lost me. Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: I think your drive letter issue might be unrelated as a non-system drive shouldn't affect your ability to log in. Do you have an alternative user account you can use to log in an view the HKLM registry hive? If so then check the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` subkeys for one with a weird suffix (.old or something, can't remember).

Comment: Isn't the User directory a system file? Because that was on this data drive. But I looked into this registry area and found nothing out of the ordinary, just all the entries set to the "F:" drive, which is what I installed them onto

Comment: @user3050461: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215 (method 1)

Comment: @horatio LOL thanks that's what I was trying to say